# Sorting by id without showing id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have simple table

```
|ID|TIME_HORIZON|
-----------------
|1 | 1W         |
|2 | 1W         |
|3 | 1M         |
|4 | 6M         |
|5 | 2Y         |
|6 | 6M         |
|7 | 2Y         |
|8 | MAX        |
```

How to select distinct values from time_horizon but in order by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `MIN` or `MAX`  with a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
    ,TIME_HORIZON
FROM Table1
GROUP BY TIME_HORIZON
ORDER BY ID;

| ID | TIME_HORIZON |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |           1W |
|  3 |           1M |
|  4 |           6M |
|  5 |           2Y |
|  8 |          MAX |
```

If you don't want to show `ID`, one option is to nest the above query.

```
select TIME_HORIZON FROM 
(
 select MIN(ID) as ID,TIME_HORIZON FROM Table1 
   GROUP BY TIME_HORIZON
  ORDER BY ID
) --where clause filtering ;
```

**EDIT** : Parentheses is required if you want to filter `TIME_HORIZON` based on `ordered max(id)` as in `where rownum >=2 and rownum < 4`  etc or else refer @mathguy's answer.

Comment: @shawnt00 : Yes. unlike in sql-server, Oracle does not expect you to put  an alias on  sub-query

Comment: I'm thinking about the nested `order by`

Comment: @shawnt00 : Yes.. this  works in Oracle and Postgres(with alias)  as far as I know .

Comment: @shawnt00 I'm not sure if Oracle guarantees the inner order to be preserved, but I've never seen otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can `ORDER BY` an expression even if you don't include it in the `SELECT` clause. In your problem, since the same `TIME_HORIZON` may appear more than once, it is not clear what you mean by "ordering it by `ID`"; but if you mean "order it by `MIN(ID)`", as in the solution you marked as correct, that can be done very simply like this:

```
select   time_horizon
from     inputs
group by time_horizon
order by min(id)
;
```

You don't have to select `min(id)` to have it available in `order by`; you can use it there directly.

Comment: It's just that If op needs additional filtering on id,with rownum etc nesting is useful...or else this is cleaner...I will add that in answer..